# Flask session storing OAuth1Session using pickle

Tags: python, flask, oauth, pickle

I'm working on oauth1 authorization and currently I'm storing a serialized `OAuth1Session` object inside a cookie which seems expensive (the size of the object is 2.6kb).

From my understanding, it is probably best to hold information that is important to access services which is just access tokens. So there are two approaches that I'm thinking of.

```py
oauthSession = OAuth1Session(
        client_key=CLIENT_KEY,
        client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
        resource_owner_key=oauthAccessTokens.get('oauth_token'),
        resource_owner_secret=oauthAccessTokens.get('oauth_token_secret'))

session['serializedSession'] = pickle.dumps(oauthSession)
session['oauthToken'] = oauthAccessTokens.get('oauth_token')
session['oauthTokenSecret'] = oauthAccessTokens.get('oauth_token_secret')
```

Then on a request, I check if `serializedSession` is in `session` with the `inSession` decorator and load the object every time I send a request:

```py
@inSession
def get(serviceRequestURL):
    oauthSession = pickle.loads(session['serializedSession'])
    return processResponse(oauthSession.get(serviceRequestURL))
```

The other way would be to store the two access tokens and create a new `OAuth1Session` object on the request and check if those two tokens exist within the session:

```py
@inSession
def get(serviceRequestURL):
    oauthSession = oauthSession = OAuth1Session(
        client_key=CLIENT_KEY,
        client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
        resource_owner_key=session['oauthToken'],
        resource_owner_secret=session['oauthTokenSecret'])
    return processResponse(oauthSession.get(serviceRequestURL))
```

It might seem like minor improvement, but I'm not sure which approach is best or if there are better approaches. The whole idea of recreating or reloading an object doesn't seem like a good solution so I'm looking for a better approach that reduces the cookie size and avoids recreating or reloading an object.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use your second way. Why would you want to save the OAuth1Session instance in session? If you want to reuse your OAuth1Session instance, you can declare it outside your function.

I suggest that you use a flask integration like https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/flask.html so that you don't have to deal with such a thing.

And the more important issue is you should not store oauth token into session, since Flask session is signed cookie, the oauth token will be exposed to client (browser).